# Linux's way to run a function inside a dynamic library (.so) via command line

Tags: linux, command-line, shared-libraries

Just wondering if there is a way to invoke a method inside a dynamic library without creating a process in Linux. In windows you can call from the command line something like `rundll32.exe my_dynamic_library.dll,my_method` and that will run the `rundll32.exe` process and it will load `my_dynamic_library.dll` and providing there is an exported method named `my_method` it will execute it. What I'm looking is to avoid having to create a separate project to wrap my `.so` into an executable when testing code that depends on a dummy process running `my_dynamic_library.dll` in the background (distributed system).

Comment: Later answers may prove me wrong, but I think the answer is we don't have such a tool (because we don't write our `.so`'s to be used that way (because we don't have such a tool (because ...)))

Comment: Yeah I've googled a little bit and doesn't seem to be any tool part of the operating system capable of wrapping a `.so` and run `void Method()` ... too bad!

Comment: It would be an easy thing to write, as long as you restrict yourself to calling a single function with no arguments. `dlopen` and `dlsym` are the functions you need. The only thing easier is... writing the program that calls a *specific* function. And that way you end up with a program you can give a reasonable name to...